# Связка андроид - 1С через вэб сервис 1С. Как аторизоваться

Tags: java, android, get, 1с, httpurlconnection

Создал в 1С вэб сервис. Делает простую выборку выкладывает в виде строки.
Подключение к сервису с любого браузера проходит отлично.

Подключение из приложения пишет ошибку файл не найден (GET запрос)
При этом любые другие сервисы (не 1с) читаются на ура.
Подозреваю что проблема в атворизации либо в заголовках запроса(???)

Пробовал так. Не работает (файл не найден)
http://192.168.0.202/TsdService/hs/tsd/Str1/ReadSpr/Str3/
http://user:password@192.168.0.202/TsdService/hs/tsd/Str1/ReadSpr/Str3/
http://192.168.0.202/TsdService/hs/tsd/Str1/ReadSpr/Str3
http://user:password@192.168.0.202/TsdService/hs/tsd/Str1/ReadSpr/Str3

А вот так все запрашивается на ура

http://192.168.0.202 (возвращается заглавная страница IIS-а)
[www.ya.ru](http://www.ya.ru) (тоже норм все)

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" );
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); // В этом месте слетает с ошибкой.
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему отключив авторизацию на вэб-сервисе 1с.
Делается это в файле default.vrd после публикации сервиса.
В строку ib добавил пользователя и пароль с минимальной ролью. (пользователь должен быть заведен в 1С)

Было

```
 ib="Srvr=&quot;MySrv&quot;;Ref=&quot;MyBase&quot;"
```

Стало

```
ib="Srvr=&quot;MySrv&quot;;Ref=&quot;MyBase&quot;;Usr=&quot;MyUser&quot;;Pwd=&quot;MyPass&quot;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Не большой спец в Java, но разве к соединению не нужно передавать логин/пароль? Если взять тот же HTTPСоединение в 1С - при создании передаётся логин и пароль. В «default.vrd»пе